# SelectionMoved listener not working when selection moved using arrow key

Tags: gojs

I am using

```
 this.diagram.commandHandler.doKeyDown
```

for movement of nodes using arrow keys,
i have a listener for any movement of nodes on the workspace

```
this.diagram.addDiagramListener('SelectionMoved', e => {
```

the above listener listens to the movement of nodes done by mouse but it doesn't when the movement is done using the arrow key.
Ideally it should listen but unfortunately it's not,
Can someone help me how to overcome this situation.
Thanks in advance!!!...

Answer (score 0):

The arrow keys do not normally move the selection, so you must have implemented some code to respond to the arrow keys to move those selected Parts.

If that's the case, then why can't you then do whatever you wanted to do in your keyboard event handler?

In other words, if you write some code that changes the **Node.location** of some node(s), there isn't supposed to be any "SelectionMoved" **DiagramEvent**.  So if you want to do something when you move a node, just do it after you have moved the node.

Comment: Please check my question, i have mentioned that i am moving the selected nodes using keyboard using  this.diagram.commandHandler.doKeyDown function, but the thing is that the SelectionMoved listener is not getting called when there is any selection movement using keyboard

Comment: I guess my answer was ambiguous.  I have clarified it.